# Keeping forward slashes in cookie PHP

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie, slash

I am building a log in page.  Right now, there is an expiration on the page that I use a cookie for.  I want the site to redirect back to the page they were on after they log in again.

For this, I use a cookie that has the name of the page stored in it (example, queue.php) and it will take them back.

This method works great if I'm going to a page that is in the same directory, but if I want to go back to a sub-directory, (for example, Deployment/deployment.php) it does not work.

I have tried urlencode(), backslashes, addslashes(), %2F in place of the forward slash, and nothing seems to be working.

This is how I am setting the cookie:

```
$url_name = "Deployment/deployment.php";
setcookie("url",$url_name);
```

Any help would be appreciated, I am completely lost.

Answer (score 2):

setrawcookie() seems to be the function you're going for. According to php.net, it is exactly the same as setcookie(), only it doesn't do any urlencoding.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where your login page is found, but if `Deployment` is a subdirectory (so one level beneath the main folder) you should add a forward slash infront of it, like so:

```
$url_name = "/Deployment/deployment.php";
setcookie("url", $url_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could `base64_encode()` the value and then `base64_decode` it upon retrieval?  Just a though.  I don't know why the forward slash wouldn't be allowed, though.  Perhaps someone else will be able to enlighten me!

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain your problem a bit more? I just tried the following, and was able to retrieve the value of the cookie just fine:

```
<?php 
$url = "http://google.com/mail";
echo "Setting cookie with value " . $url . "</br>";
setcookie("url", $url);
echo "The cookie is: " . $_COOKIE['url'] . "</br>";
?>
```

Comment: This will not work. the superglobals are NOT touched by php after the script initialization is complete. The new cookie will only show up in the cookies super on the next page load. As well, you have an echo before the setcookie call, so all this produces is a "headers already sent" error and cannot EVER set a cookie.

Comment: Right, you'd have to refresh the page in order to get the value of the cookie. Also, I tested the code before I posted it, and a "Headers already sent" error was not raised.

Comment: @Marc B: Perhaps he has output_buffering set to TRUE in the PHP's ini configuration; that would not cause a "headers already sent" error.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly doesn't work? As stated in [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php):

> Note that the value portion of the cookie will automatically be urlencoded when you send the cookie, and when it is received, it is automatically decoded and assigned to a variable by the same name as the cookie name.

So there's no need to manually encode/decode. I don't think the slash in the `$url_name` is the problem. I suspect the path you're redirecting to is somehow incorrect, but I can't check without more code.